# ySearch Markers

Tags: dna, y-dna

Can any one explain why some of the test on ySearch are listed as FTDNA but have a different set of markers? I.E. in some cases the first 37 markers are missing, in some cases there seems to be a random set of markers for comparison.
[image]

Comment: ySearch is subsidized by ftDNA I believe. To answer your question though can you provide a screenshot masking any user identifiers so I can more specifically answer?

Comment: Here is a screen shot;

Comment: Please use the "Edit" button at the bottom of the post to add additional detail, including your screenshot